# Rearrange explorer windows in taskbar

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, taskbar

I want to rearrange explorer windows in task bar in windows 7. I am able to rearrange windows of different applications but I can't rearrange windows of explorer

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Taskbar tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker). I haven't used it myself but it seems like it might serve your purpose. It has the option to drag within groups using right click or not group applications at all.

[image]